# iOS Swift, how to delete a UIView in a TableViewCell and adjustment cell height?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add or delete some view in a TableViewCell dynamically
And I want the cell Height could be adjusted to the cell content height when I delete the UIView in cell.

below is my demo, I use the

```swift
self.frame.size.height -= 100
```

to adjust cell height, but the result is not so good.

```swift
import UIKit
import SnapKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let table = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 1200))
        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self
        table.estimatedRowHeight = 1
        table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        table.separatorColor = UIColor.blue
        table.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "identifierid")
        view.addSubview(table)
    }

}
class CustomCell:UITableViewCell {
    let btn:UIButton = {
        let btn  = UIButton()
        btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        btn.layer.borderWidth = 1
        btn.setTitle("delete red view", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        return btn
    }()

    let v:UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return v
    }()


    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.addSubview(btn)
        btn.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
            make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 150,height: 50))
        }
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteCellImg), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.contentView.addSubview(v)
        v.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(btn.snp.bottom)
            make.left.equalTo(btn)
            make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
        }

    }

    @objc func deleteCellImg() {
        v.removeFromSuperview()
        self.frame.size.height -= 100  //100 is the red view height
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifierid", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

The result is showed below

[image: iOS simulator screenshot]

When I delete a view in a cell,I don't want the other cell height would be influenced.So is there some detail I ignore?

Comment: **UNIVERSAL SOLUTION** : Use UIStackView.

Comment: After deleting view, call `tableview.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

call removeFromSuperview() while removing the view. This will be done in your Custom Cell class.

Then reload table view through table.reloadData().

If the row height is still misleading use constraints or height for row.